# Application doesn't launch with location key after a significant location change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, cllocationmanager, ios7

My application uses the core location also after the application terminates with the method startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in CLLocationManager class.

My application launches with a location key in iOS 5 and 6 in the method:
- (BOOL) application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions;
in AppDelegate class and everything works well.

But in iOS-7 betas the application doesn't launch with a location key after a significant location change.

Has anybody encountered this problem?

I tried it on a simulator and in the device.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem in my app, when the app was terminated by user from app switcher.
But it does launch with location key if it was terminated by OS for low memory or other reason.

It is the expected result from iOS7 unfortunately. An official apple response I got from one of their evangelists:

> If a user swipes up in the app switcher then the OS will not launch
>   the app unless explicitly told to do so by the user.  So no, SLC will
>   not be launching the app, nor will silent notifications.  The only
>   thing that will launch the app at that point is the user tapping the
>   icon.  The intention here is that the user has expressed their choice
>   of not having that app running any more for any reason, so we honor
>   that.  In this situation, there's really nothing that you can do.  The
>   next time the user launches the app you can let them know that some of
>   the data may be missing, although you really cannot tell whether
>   there's missing data or not (i.e. you might have been killed by the OS
>   in the background and the user may not have moved thereby not
>   triggering any SLC notifications).  My suggestion would be to gather
>   the data you can within the policies of the OS and if the user has
>   manually killed the app then respect that wish and don't do anything. 
>   By all means, feel free to file a bug report if this change in
>   behavior winds up causing problems for you or (especially) confusion
>   for your users.

Attach link to Apple DEV forums:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/882691#882691