# iOS 7 Significant location change launch after termination

Tags: ios, ios7

My app automatically wakes up after termination when new location data arrives on iOS 6, but not on iOS 7.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setBackgroundRefreshStatus]` is `UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable`.

In `Info.plist` I set `UIBackgroundModes` with value "location".

`CLLocationManager` started this way:

```
- (void) start {
  if (locationManaher == nil) {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate        = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
  }

  [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

  CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D oldCoordinate = oldLocation.coordinate;

  if (newCoordinate.latitude == oldCoordinate.latitude && newCoordinate.longitude == oldCoordinate.longitude) return;

  float distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];

  if (distance < distanceFilter) {
    //send to server 
  }
}
```

Does anybody know where is a problem?

Comment: BTW, I don't believe you need that background mode setting [for significant change service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22). That's only needed for standard location services.

Comment: Possible dublicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7

Comment: I have same problem, Do you have any solution ??

Comment: It's iOS 7 feature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212171/application-doesnt-launch-with-location-key-after-a-significant-location-change

Answer (score 4):

It is 7.0 iOS feature, if user closes the app manually (from home button double click), the application doesn't triggers on location change.

Comment: I couldn't see any kinds of information in Location programming guide. Could you please provide a link for it?

Answer (score 1):

The [`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateToLocation%3afromLocation%3a) method is deprecated, effective iOS 6. You should use now [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a).

Comment: In my code I use both methods:
1. - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
2. - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation