# CoreLocation - region monitoring issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location, region, region-monitoring

My code is working for `iOS 6` . but problem is in `iOS7` only  `didStartMonitoringForRegion` getting called , didEnterRegion and didEExitRegion not getting called ....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    m_pLocatiomManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    m_pLocatiomManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    m_pLocatiomManager.delegate = self;
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [m_pLocatiomManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

method to add region

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 7.0) 
{
    float rad = 200;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startLocation;
    startLocation.latitude = 12.9667 ;
    startLocation.longitude =77.5667 ;
    CLCircularRegion * reg1 = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:startLocation radius:rad identifier:@"location"];
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringForRegion:reg1];
}
else
{
    float rad = 200;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startLocation;
    startLocation.latitude = 12.9667;
    startLocation.longitude = 77.5667; 
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringForRegion:[[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:startLocation radius:rad identifier:@"location"]];
}
```

corelocation delegates ----

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{    
    NSLog(@"region entered %@",region.description);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
   NSLog(@"region exit  %@",region.description);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"region monitoring stared");
}
```

Thanks .

Comment: Are you testing this on a device?

Comment: simulator by using gpx files

Comment: I would try to test it on a device since region monitoring uses cell towers and wifi to get a location fix. I've also had problems when testing this on the simulator. Also, if you haven't done so I suggest you implement `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError` just to make sure everything is working correctly.

Comment: @GadMarkovits is right, simulator behavior is unpredictable when you try to do region monitoring. I'm surprised that it works on iOS6. Second do not use that system to check version, use the one provided by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html look at the bottom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i solved this ....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    m_pLocatiomManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    m_pLocatiomManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    m_pLocatiomManager.delegate = self;
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [m_pLocatiomManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

in method to add region . . .

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 7.0) 
{
    float rad = 100;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startLocation;
    startLocation.latitude = 12.9667 ;
    startLocation.longitude =77.5667 ;
    CLCircularRegion * reg1 = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:startLocation radius:rad identifier:@"location"];
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringForRegion:reg1];
}
else
{
    float rad = 100;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startLocation;
    startLocation.latitude = 12.9667;
    startLocation.longitude = 77.5667; 
    [m_pLocatiomManager startMonitoringForRegion:[[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:startLocation radius:rad identifier:@"location"]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry so what is different?

Comment: @Daniel CLCircularRegion * reg1 = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:startLocation radius:rad identifier:@"location"]; // creating object using "initWithCenter:radius:identifier" in second case

Comment: @RIYAZ can you please share the code related with SignificantLocationChanges. As I am unable to make it work on iOS7. i.e. If my app is not active, the SignificantLocationChanges doesn't work. similar to issue mentioned in here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048526/ios-7-significant-location-change-launch-after-termination